# An AxoCover-like experience for .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using [AxoCover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover) extension, and I'm used to this coverage visualization like so in the screenshot below:

[image]

Can't really find anything that would do the same thing for .NET Core. Can anybody point me out any .NET Core alternative for this extension?

Comment: short answer: no. Alternative: visual studio code with code gutters: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AutomaticUnitTestingInNETCorePlusCodeCoverageInVisualStudioCode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is the free Visual Studio extension [Fine Code Coverage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FortuneNgwenya.FineCodeCoverage), that does what you want. It supports the full .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Here's a screenshot showing the coverage visualization:
[image: Screenshot]